# LaTeX display of exponential pushed down with respect to baseline

Tags: bug, mathjax

This is hardly important, but ...
In [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/292684/6094), I used the LaTeX `O(n \epsilon^{1-d})` to display
$O(n \epsilon^{1-d})$, but this is what it looks like to me (in Chrome 64.0.3282.140 under MacOS 10.13.3):

---

[image: latex]

---

Note the $\epsilon^{1-d}$ is pushed downward, likely by the line above.
But the use of the same LaTeX in this post looks fine (to me).

Is this a MathJax / Chrome bug?

Comment: What [MathJax renderer](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=mathjax+renderer) are you using? Does the display change if you switch to another one?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I don't know. How can I determine which MathJax renderer is installed?

Comment: You can change the renderer in the [MathJax menu](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=mathjax+menu) which you get by right clicking on any MathJax formula. $x^2+y^2=z^2$ The links I gave in the previous comment and in this one show a few screenshots.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks. I see I am using HTML-CSS. MathML is not supported natively in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a combined screenshot of three browsers, from left to right:
Firefox 58.0.2, Safari 11.0.3, Chrome 64.0.3282.140 (all on MacOS 10.13.3); only Chrome shows the misalignment:

[image]

In each case the MathJax renderer was HTML-CSS, so that does not seem to be the source of the difference.